# Calling Rust from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rust, node-ffi

I was trying to build a simple rust rss 'harvester' for my soup.io blog and then post those entries to diaspora with node.js (since there is an npm package for that)

I want to learn how to use rust from node so this is why I'm building this project.

My problem is that I don't know how to call the `ffi` function with the right types.

```
var lib = ffi.Library('target/debug/libmain', {
    'get_soup': ['Vec<Post>', ['String']]
});
```

The `'Vec<Post>'` doesn't work.
I get that I have to use `ref` for that.
But I don't really know how and what that actually does.

I understand that I have to translate the rust types to javascript?

**How can I use `Vec<Post>` in my ffi function?**

my github project for that: [Realtin/suppe](https://github.com/Realtin/suppe)

and here the relevant code:

## Rust Code:

```
extern crate rss;
extern crate hyper;

use rss::Rss;
use std::io::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Post  {
    title: String,
    link: String,
    description: String,
}

fn main() {
    let user = "realtin".to_string();
    let vec = get_soup(&user);
    println!("{:?}", vec[vec.len()-1]);
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn get_soup(user: &str) ->Vec<Post>{
    let url = format!("http://{}.soup.io/rss", user);
    let mut vec = Vec::new();

    let client = hyper::Client::new();
    let mut response = client.get(&url).send().unwrap();

    let mut suppe = String::new();
    let _= response.read_to_string(&mut suppe);

    let rss::Rss(channel) = suppe.parse::<rss::Rss>().unwrap();

    for item in channel.items.into_iter().rev() {
      let item_object = Post {
           title: item.title.unwrap(),
           link: item.link.unwrap(),
           description: item.description.unwrap(),
        };
        vec.push(item_object);
    }
    return vec;
}
```

## NodeJS code:

```
var ref = require('ref');
var StructType = require("ref-struct");
var ffi = require('ffi');

var Post = StructType({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  description: String,
});
// var vecPost = ref.refType(ref.types.Object);

var lib = ffi.Library('target/debug/libmain', {
    'get_soup': ['Vec<Post>', ['String']]
});

var posts = lib.get_soup("realtin");
```

Comment: You may be interested in [*The Rust FFI Omnibus*](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/) as well.

Comment: @Shepmaster oh this is amazing! I was looking for something like this!

Comment: Great! Be sure to file any issues on Github if you are looking for any specific examples or if anything can be made clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer: you cannot export any Rust function for FFI bindings, you need to specifically export Rust functions compatible with C.

Specifically, this means that you need to expose only C-struct compatible objects OR expose opaque pointers (which can only be manipulated through Rust functions).

In your case, `Vec<Post>` is not compatible with usage in FFI, because `Vec` is not.

You can find more information in the [FFI Guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html).

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense :)

Answer (score -1):

Some data types can be passed directly, using your approach

Export Rust using FFI
https://svartalf.info/posts/2019-03-01-exposing-ffi-from-the-rust-library/

and then call it from nodejs from using something like https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi

May be not using structure that you require, but you can convert data in one or both ends.
As a last resort you can use JSON. There will be some overhead but not a lot

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498913/3232611

can use protocol buffers, if JSON performance is bottleneck, but in most cases its not worth complexity